# "людей других сословий" или "людей из других сословий" как правильно?

Tags: грамматика

> Дворянам того времени можно было не знать родной язык, но французский
>   истинный дворянин знать был обязан, несмотря на людей из других
>   сословий: “Шишков, прости: Не знаю, как перевести”.

И кстати, а если я пропускаю слово язык и пишу "русский" или "французский" без этого слова, могут ли посчитать это на ГИА грамматической ошибкой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба варианта корректны, но ГИА (ОГЭ) предполагает письменный язык, а "людей из других сословий" в современном языке носит больше  разговорный характер, следовательно, лучше использовать литературный вариант "людей других сословий". Хотя мы же говорим и даже пишем "Он был из дворян", "из купцов" и т.д. Всё нормально, это не ошибка.

А вот сама фраза "*но французский истинный дворянин знать был обязан, несмотря на людей из других сословий*" выглядит не совсем литературно, лучше написать "в отличие от других сословий". **Несмотря на = вопреки чему-то**, в этом предложении не совсем уместно.

Пропуск слова *язык* корректен, это средство убрать повтор, не ошибка.

Comment: "Дворянам того времени можно было не знать родной язык, но французский истинный дворянин знать был обязан. Хотя низшие сословия могли не знать этот язык". Можно ли так написать? Может ли сословие знать что-либо? На гиа вообще допустимы фразы в частично переносном значении?

Comment: @аscobar  Может, лучше "...представители низших сословий..."

Comment: На мой взгляд, вариант "**из** другого сословия" - не просто _разговорная_ допустимость, а выражение, полезное (возможно даже, более точное) для указания на человека, _оказавшегося не к месту и задержавшегося не в своей среде_. Нейтральный (беспредложный) же вариант указывает на принадлежность к другому сословию человека, о котором просто зашла речь (по какому-л. поводу).